# Push notification onMessageReceived method in FirebaseMessagingService is not called?

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I already Implemented the service in android manifest and still no response from the **FirebaseMessagingService** service. The weird thing is that the notification is successfully sent. When I tried to debug and add the breakpoint to the **onMessageReceived** method I can received the notification but when I install it first without attaching the debug the service is not called so no callback response from the **FirebaseMessagingService**. So basically  **FirebaseMessagingService** will work if I debug the app but when it is not in debug no callback is called from the **FirebaseMessagingService**.

The phone that I used is Samsung  galaxy J7pro android version OREO(API 27).

**AndroidManifest.xml**
added the following in the manifest file.

```
 <service android:name=".services.InstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".services.NotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**build.gradle**(app)
added the following in the build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    // dbManagerPushNotification.DBManagerPushNotification(this);


    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Map<String, String> remoteMessage_getData = remoteMessage.getData();

        String community_slug = remoteMessage_getData.get("community_slug");
        String conversation_id = remoteMessage_getData.get("conversation_id");
        String sender_id = remoteMessage_getData.get("sender_id");
        final String message_id = remoteMessage_getData.get("message_id");
        String message = remoteMessage_getData.get("message");
        String convo_type = remoteMessage_getData.get("convo_type");
        String created_at = remoteMessage_getData.get("created_at");
        String title = remoteMessage_getData.get("title");
        Log.i("push_notification", "onMessageReceived: " + message);

        final String channel_id = title + community_slug;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);


        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.putExtra("message_id", message_id);
        intent.putExtra("conversation_id", conversation_id);
        intent.putExtra("sender_id", sender_id);
        intent.putExtra("community_slug", community_slug);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), message_id.hashCode(), intent, 0);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder_title = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);
        StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        spannableStringBuilder_title.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id, title, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION).build();
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.WHITE);
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_logo)
                .setColor(0xECEFF1)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setGroup(convo_type)
                .setGroupAlertBehavior(GROUP_ALERT_CHILDREN)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.selection_orange))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

        String community_notif = "  " + community_slug + ": ";
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(community_notif);
        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.selection_orange)), 0, community_notif.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


        NotificationCompat.Builder summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channel_id)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_logo)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle().setSummaryText(TextUtils.concat(spannableStringBuilder, title)).setBigContentTitle(TextUtils.concat(spannableStringBuilder, title)))
                .setGroup(convo_type)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setGroupAlertBehavior(GROUP_ALERT_CHILDREN)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.selection_orange))
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(message_id.hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
        notificationManager.notify(channel_id.hashCode(), summaryNotification.build());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: how do you know it's not working? There is literally nothing different when you run your app in debug mode, other than a debugger being attached to the process

Comment: @TimCastelijns thank you for the reply, that's the reason Why I'm confused. When  I installed the app and without debugging I don't have any response from the FirebaseMessagingService but when I debug it the notifications are showing immediately. I also thing maybe the server is taking long for sending the push notification but that's not the case because I've waited like 10minutes but no callback is made.

Comment: I also read from the other thread issue that there are two types of Setting the priority of a message in FCM, in our server side it was set to  Data messages and priority high(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)  but still it is not making a callback.